# getting underline as error in syntax of typescript not able to understand

Tags: typescript, angular5

In my typescript I am getting an error as :

`Property 'results' does not exist on type Object`;
But the code works fine. I require know  what I missed here. any one help me?

Error:

[image: Error]

here is my code (TS) :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

interface CountryDetails {
  countryLongName: string;
  countryShortName: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class ServerService {

// latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false
    googleApi:string = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=";
    postParam: any;
    options: any;
    countryDetails:CountryDetails;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.postParam = {
        "clientId": "RETAIL",
        "spvParam": {
            "productCode": "PDO",
            "consigneeCountry": "MY",
            "salesOrgRef": "TH61",
            "salesOrgFacilityCode": "THBKK1",
            "salesOrgChnl": "eCommerce",
            "pickUpAcctRef": "5999999108",
            "facilityId": "MYKUL1"
        }
    }

    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  }

    public getCountry(lat,lan):Observable<any>{

        return this.http.get(this.googleApi+lat+','+lan+'&sensor=false').map( data => {

            data.results.map( array => {
                let details = array.address_components.find( obj => obj.types.includes("country") );
                this.countryDetails.countryLongName = details.long_name;
                this.countryDetails.countryShortName = details.short_name;
            })

            return this.countryDetails;
        })

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Typescript compiler checks that results variable. To fix this  explicitly tell TypeScript **`type`** of data as **`any`** ,

```
return this.http.get(this.googleApi+lat+','+lan+'&sensor=false').map((data:any) => {
```

Comment: the same code I a am getting this error as well `ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'countryLongName' of undefined` - help me?

Comment: can you post your HTML

Comment: I don't sending to html at all, calling from one of resolve service. do you require that?

Comment: ok then isuse might be your response. check what type of data you get there

Comment: if I remove the object interface and set like :  `countryDetails:any = {};` then error goes. what is the issue with my interface I use?

Comment: need to check your interface. you can handle that error as your said above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170010/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-sajeetharan).